# Why is my regex not matching?

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

I have a string like that:

```
<li class="level0 nav-2 last level-top parent">
   <a href="#" class="level-top"><span>XYZ</span></a>
   <ul class="level0">
      <li class="level1 nav-2-1 first"><a href="#"><span>Farben</span></a></li>
      <li class="level1 nav-2-2 last"><a href="#"><span>Muster</span></a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

Now I want to match the last li, but only if at some position in the string it says XYZ. I tried

```
/<li class="level1 nav-(\d+)-(\d+) last">.+(<\/li>)/
```

Which finds the last li, but I cant figure out how to add the only if its followed by XYZ. I tried

```
/.*XYZ.*<li class="level1 nav-(\d+)-(\d+) last">.+(<\/li>)/
```

but that did not work.

Ideas? Thanks :)

Comment: do **NOT** use regexes to match xml/html. you'll just rip out your hair. Use DOM operations instead.

Comment: If you want to parse HTML/XML you should use a parser that would do that much faster and with a better accuracy than regular expressions

Comment: Well, I want to replace stuff according to that match later ... I guess thats not possible with a parser?

Comment: DOM parsers are usually part of DOM manipulation libraries, so yes you can.

Comment: Greediness. -- Contrary to SO wisdom, one can use regex for such tasks; it's just more effort, and inadvisable if you're unversed with its syntax and behaviour; for unnormalized and arbitrary HTML input moreso.

Comment: With all that said, I'm not sure how well a DOM parser would handle the "only if the string contains XYZ somewhere" condition.

Comment: @Barmar: That's easy. You'll need to iterate the DOM tree recursively and check the `textNode` property of each, to find a match. It's indeed more cumbersome, but the result would be much more stable and robust. It won't break on the slightest change.

Comment: @barmar: xpath: `//*[contains(text(), "xyz")]`

Comment: Take a look at http://htmlparsing.com/regex.html for details about why regexes for HTML parsing is bad news.  See http://htmlparsing.com/php.html for examples of how to do it with the DOM module.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to use a REGEX :

```
XYZ(.*\n( |\t)*.*)*<li class="level1 nav-(\d+)-(\d+) last">.+(<\/li>)
```

do you need to precise "level1 nav-(\d+)-(\d+)" ?

what will you need to use later ?

maybe you can just catch the part needed as :

```
XYZ(.*\n( |\t)*.*)*<li class=".*last">(.+)<\/li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the regex:

```
/XYZ(?s:.*)<li class="level1 nav-(\d+)-(\d+) last">.+(<\/li>)/
```

The `s` modifier in the subpattern allows `.` to match newlines.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this very easy with [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/), which is a php port of jQuery

Then use for example

```
$liElm = pq("ul li:last:contains('xyz')");
```

Notice that phpQuery isn't as fast as regular expressions but much easier to handle and much more comfortable.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it.

I want to point out as I always do with Markup parsing, that DOM Navigational tools are best for Well-Formed Markup.  You can use HTML Parsers to translate it into an XML Document and use XPath, or many other options.  Sometimes this is overkill or not even possible with Non-Well-Formed HTML, or other Document Types.  That being said, your request (in my mind) translates to:

Match the ListItem HTML Object <li...</li that is NOT Followed by another ListItem Thusly, the last one, but require that it is preceeded by the string "xyz"

```
(?is)(?<=xyz.*?)<li\s(?!.*?<li).*?</li>
```

This Regex uses Case Insensitive and SingleLine options, requires that "xyz" and anything else exists prior to the match, finds a ListItem not followed by another ListItem, and gets that entire ListItem.  No CaptureGroup is required since the Lookahead and Lookbehind are Zero-Width assertions and don't capture.  So this is Capture Group 0 for your whole match.

Mario Suggested Greediness, which would be fine for small chunks, but for large documents it entails a lot of backtracking.

```
(?is)xyz.*(<li.*?</li>)
```

This Regex requires you to use a Capture Group, though, since the match is greedy.  Not that Capture Groups are bad, just a bit more code.